# Getting Error while migrating Play Framework 2.1.0 to 2.2.6

Tags: java, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.0, akka

I update the play version 2.1.0 to 2.2.6 and compilation is success but when i am trying to run play application it's showing as below error :-

```
Uncaught error from thread [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[play]
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: play.mvc.Action.call(Lplay/mvc/Http$Context;)Lplay/libs/F$Promise;
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$3.apply(JavaAction.scala:91)
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$3.apply(JavaAction.scala:90)
    at play.core.j.FPromiseHelper$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(FPromiseHelper.scala:82)
    at play.core.j.FPromiseHelper$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(FPromiseHelper.scala:82)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:251)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:249)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext$$anon$2.run(HttpExecutionContext.scala:37)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:42)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
[error] a.a.ActorSystemImpl - Uncaught error from thread [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: play.mvc.Action.call(Lplay/mvc/Http$Context;)Lplay/libs/F$Promise;
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$3.apply(JavaAction.scala:91) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$3.apply(JavaAction.scala:90) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
    at play.core.j.FPromiseHelper$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(FPromiseHelper.scala:82) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
    at play.core.j.FPromiseHelper$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(FPromiseHelper.scala:82) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:251) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:249) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
[ERROR] [01/12/2018 12:40:36.357] [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [ActorSystem(play)] Uncaught error from thread [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: play.mvc.Action.call(Lplay/mvc/Http$Context;)Lplay/libs/F$Promise;
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$3.apply(JavaAction.scala:91)
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$3.apply(JavaAction.scala:90)
    at play.core.j.FPromiseHelper$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(FPromiseHelper.scala:82)
    at play.core.j.FPromiseHelper$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(FPromiseHelper.scala:82)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:251)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:249)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext$$anon$2.run(HttpExecutionContext.scala:37)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:42)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

**added new file Build.sbt**

```
name := "MyApp"

 version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

 libraryDependencies ++= Seq(   javaJdbc,   javaEbean,   cache )

 play.Project.playJavaSettings
```

**changed sbt-plugin version in project/plugins.sbt**

```
 // Comment to get more information during initialization logLevel :=
 Level.Warn

 // The Typesafe repository resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at
 "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

 // Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
 addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.6")
```

**change the Dependency in project/Build.scala file**

```
 import sbt._ import Keys._ import play.Project._

 object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

   val appName         = "MyApp"   
   val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

   val appDependencies = Seq(
           "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "3.6.9.Final",
       "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18",
       javaCore,
       javaJdbc,  javaJpa,  "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901.jdbc4",  "org.json"%"org.json"%"chargebee-1.0",
       "com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-mailer" % "2.1-RC2", "org.codehaus.jackson" % "jackson-mapper-asl" % "1.9.9" )

   val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion,
 appDependencies).settings(
     // Add your own project settings here   )

 }
```

Can you please help me on same.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Seems that there are incompatibilities between libraries that you use. Please note any [eviction warnings](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Library-Management.html#Eviction+warning) that might be printed during startup of the sbt console. As a last resort, you can investigate your [dependency graph](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) and see if there are any incompatible libraries.